# Screen turned upside down during start up. Ctrl+Alt+Up does nothing

Tags: windows-10, setup

I need to set up some laptops and have never used Windows 10 before.

The Windows key is on a sticker underneath the laptop, and when I picked it up to copy it, the screen turned upside down. Windows isn't set up yet so I don't have access to desktop>properties. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> shortcut also does nothing (it just scrolls the license agreement part).

How can I turn the screen back the right way without access to the shortcut or the desktop properties?

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Comment: It re-opened to the same screen ("here's the legal stuff...") as when I closed it. I've also tried shaking it. It's an "HP EliteBook"

Comment: Go to graphics properties and try.

Comment: @vembutech: How you do that when Windows isn't yet set up, and you're stuck at the licensing agreement screen?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to flip it back by tilting the whole notebook forwards. Turning it upside down or sideways wasn't doing anything.

Answer (score -1):

In Start menu go to Settings > System > Display. Click in Orientation box and switch from Landscape (flipped) to Landscape.

Comment: I haven't completed setup yet so there's no start menu.